# Angular Material 6: how to hide a div on small display

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to hide `div 2` on mobile phones:

```
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2 is really big.</div>
<div>div 3</div>
```

Could not find anything on the official documentation at https://material.angular.io/

Comment: If you just want to hide it (not prevent it from ever being rendered / bound), the easiest solution might just be to use [css media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp). Is there a reason you aren't using media queries to show/hide?

Comment: You could also use [Angular Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API) which handles media queries for you. For example `<div fxShow fxHide.xs="true">div 2 is really big.</div>`